# scrapy-splash do not crawl recursively with CrawlerSpider

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I have integrated scrapy-splash in my CrawlerSpider process_request in rules like this:

```
 def process_request(self,request):
    request.meta['splash']={
        'args': {
            # set rendering arguments here
            'html': 1,
        }
    }
    return request
```

The problem is that the crawl renders just urls in the first depth,
I wonder also how can I get response even with bad http code or redirected reponse;

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to this: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/92

In short, try to add this to your parsing callback function:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    """Parse response into item also create new requests."""

    page = RescrapItem()
    ...
    yield page

    if isinstance(response, (HtmlResponse, SplashTextResponse)):
        seen = set()
        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                     if lnk not in seen]
            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)
            for link in links:
                seen.add(link)
                r = SplashRequest(url=link.url, callback=self._response_downloaded, 
                                              args=SPLASH_RENDER_ARGS)
                r.meta.update(rule=rule, link_text=link.text)
                yield rule.process_request(r)
```

In case, you wonder why this could return both items and new requests. Here is from the doc: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

> In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return
>   either dicts with extracted data, Item objects, **Request objects**, or an
>   **iterable of these objects**. Those Requests will also contain a callback
>   (maybe the same) and will then be downloaded by Scrapy and then their
>   response handled by the specified callback.